# Can I mimic Arduino Ethernet library through serial?

Tags: arduino, serial

I'm ordering an Ethernet Shield for a project I have planned, but before make the investment, I want to make sure the project will work. Eventually it will communicate with a website via ethernet, but I was wondering if I could test this through my PC, using it simply to route page requests, so that I can easily adapt it for the ethernet shield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the Arduino can do it, but you can look at the possibility of implementing [SLIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol). It's designed to layer TCP/IP over serial communications.

You can [configure](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linux_Networking/SLIP_server) a PC as the SLIP server, for the device to login and route packets through.

**Edit: Turns out there's an Arduino SLIP [library](http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/SerialIP) that does that exactly!**

Comment: That does look like my best option. I tried it out but I couldn't get it to show up on my network, and I can't ping it. My PC is running Ubuntu, and I followed the instructions. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: can't help you there as i dun use the arduino. however, SLIP is the technique used.